# Exposed HTML on the "Confirm Your New Account" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, sign-up

While testing the signup process on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/signup), I noticed a bit of text that should be bold, but is code instead:

[image: You are about to create a new account on <span class="make-it-bold">Seasoned Advice</span> using a login from]

I haven't looked to see if it's a problem on other sites and I'm using a Chrome incognito window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Whoops. This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: The line was "make it so", not "make it bold", Number One. ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson, pretend that it at least kinda sorta but not really rhymes. Engage. ;)

Comment: Who is it on the pic?

Comment: @nicael http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/facepalm